# Ordering a list of complexities (Big O)

Tags: big-o

Given a list of complexities:

[image]

How do you order then in their Big O order?

I think the answer is below?

[image]

Question now is how does `log(n!)` become `n log(n)`. Also I don't know if I got the n! and (n-1)! right. Is it possible that c^n can be bigger than n!? When c > n?

In general how do I visualize such Big O problem ... it took me quite long to do this ... compared to coding so far ... Any resources, videos MIT Open Courseware resources, something with explaination

Comment: I found it very instructive to plot various functions in Excel to visually understand how each grows as N increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to see how the functions grow. Here's a quick plot from Wolfram Alpha:

[**link**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20n%5En,%202%5E%282n%29,log%28n!%29%20from%200%20to%2010)

In general, `n^n` grows much faster than `c^n` for any `n` greater than some `n_0` (because `n` *will* overtake `c` at some point, even if c is extremely large). log grows much slower than quadratic or exponential, and slightly faster than linear.

For `O(log(n!)) = O(nlogn)`, I believe there was something called Stirling's Approximation. It boils down to seeing that `O(n!) = O(n^n)` as `n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2*1`, so `n^n = n*n*n*...*n` is an upper bound. It can be proven that is it a lower bound as well, but you don't need that.

Since `log(n^n) = nlogn` by log rules, `O(log(n!) = O(log(n^n)) = O(nlogn)`.